# Цикл foreach с несколькими условиями

Tags: php, циклы, foreach

У меня есть вот такой запрос в таблице. Кроме prod_ves_input у меня есть несколько массива prod_price_input и prod_edizm. Как сделать чтобы эти данные одновременно записывались в таблицу

```
    foreach($_REQUEST['prod_ves_input'] as $prod_ves_input)
    {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO product_price(product_id,ves)
    VALUES(                     
    '".$id."',
    '".$prod_ves_input."'                       
    )");                        
    }
```

Comment: Какая у вас версия php и почему такая старая?

Comment: Вообще можно реализовать это?

Comment: foreach($_REQUEST['prod_ves_input'] as $i => $prod_ves_input) { $prod_price_input = $_REQUEST['prod_ves_input'][$i]

Comment: что значит одновременно записывались? какая связь между этими массивами (величинами) ? Вы хотите в цикле одновременно двигаться по нескольким массивам?

Comment: Да именно так..

Comment: Небольшой оффтоп=) Зачем использовать $_REQUEST? Это конечно моё мнение но как по мне лучше использовать контекстные _GET, _POST, _COOKIE так хотя бы понятно что и откуда приходит а то  вы сейчас пишите и понимаете что и откуда а потом кто то другой будет дорабатывать или вы сами через пол года и думать а что откуда приходит...

Answer (score -1):

Вот что получилось сделать. 
 1 Сначала мы создаем части запросов к базе данных методом перебора массива. 
 2 Далее мы этот массив переводим в строку. 
 3 Далее мы создаем конечный запрос к базе данных 
4 Далее мы передаем этот запрос в метод ***mysqli_query*** 
5 Ура все наши записи в базе данных :)

Таким подходом мы делаем только один запрос к базе данных а не много, то есть в начале мы формируем сам запрос и только потом записываем данные

```
// Тут будут храниться наши данные в виде массива
$query_elems = array();

foreach ($products as $product) {

  $query_elems[] =  "('" . $product['product_id'] . "', '". $product['ves'] 
  ."')";

}
// Переводим массив в строку.
$arr_to_string = implode (  ',', $query_elems );

// Создание запроса
$query = "INSERT INTO product_price(product_id,ves) VALUES " . $arr_to_string;

// Записываем данные
if ( mysqli_query($link, $query) === TRUE ) {
    printf("Done");
}
```

Comment: А если там 100000 строк которые надо записать? Или ошибка каких-либо входных данных как это потом отлаживать?

Comment: Для этого нужно проверять входные данные if(!empty(....)){...} или в случае массива if(isset(массив['ключ'])){...}

Comment: А если ключ product_id уникальный? И вы записываете уже второй продукт с таким id?

Comment: 1 Само сабой product_id должен быть уникальным без если. 2 Если архитектура базки составлена правильно то записать в базку вы не сможете дублированный ключ (product_id) если стоит primary_key если вы это имели ввиду под уникальным ключом

Comment: Это все конечно ужас и инъекции

Comment: Почему должен быть уникальным я лишь привожу пример? Это просто идентификатор продукта, и не обязательно примари... Есть такие ключи как например UNIQUE что бы у вас не повторялся ves и product_id вместе что то типа `UNIQUE unique_product_ves(product_id, ves);`

Comment: А ещё по хорошему биндить параметры а не напрямую вставлять их, теперь вам надо создавать массив параметров и представьте как у вас это будет обрастать... Лучше много запросов но с биндами параметров чем один на множество вставок

Comment: Э. А в каком смысле "удалось сделать"? Вы с автором вопроса вместе работаете что ли?

Comment: Впрочем нет. У автора же совсем другой вопрос был, вообще не о том

Comment: Так вопрос совсем о другом причем тут иньекции. Разве автор вопроса что то говорил об иньекциях?

Comment: Валтер вы вообще о чем? Что за бинды я вас не понимаю?

Comment: ТС спрашивал как обходить сразу два массива... Бинды bind_param

Comment: Так у него тут один массив передается в Request а не несколько вы посмотрите на код который он предоставил

Comment: Вы вопрос прочтите внимательней

Comment: И в его коде уже все colums определены а не разные если вы про bind params и т д

Comment: У него mysql а не mysqli

Comment: речь сейчас не об авторе. код в **ответе** уязвим к инъекциям. это очень плохо, поскольку stack overflow - это публичный ресурс, и ответ потенциально могут увидеть сотни людей.  Вы на сайте явно человек новый, и рассматриваете свой ответ как обращение персонально к автору вопроса. Но надо всегда иметь в виду множество людей, ктоторые так же увидят этот код.Поэтому надо очень ответственно подходить к ответам

Comment: И кроме того, данный ответ вообще никак не затрагивает тот вопрос, который был задан.

Comment: Ну в таком случае смысл писать вначале про иньекции? Ваши комментарии тоже не уместны к моему ответу или вам больше делать нечего? Предоставьте свои ответы, чтож вы тут умничаете не по теме и время свое тратите?

Comment: Так вам же сейчас объяснили что ваш код уязвим к инъекциям, вдруг кто то посмотрит ваш ответ и скопирует код?

Comment: Не стоит агрессивно реагировать. Мы здесь все делаем одно дело - помогаем другим разработчикам. Но помощь должна быть адекватной, а не так что однй проблему решаем - десять создаём. Вы здесь человек новый, многого не знаете. Мы просто стараемся объяснить, как написать хороший ответ.

Comment: Ну скопирует  и что и дополнит если нужно будет, время свое сэкономит и поймет что лучше делать один запрос к базке а не в цикле делать множество как кто то тут советует

Comment: Ну... Раз уж на то пошло... Я бы вообще на очередях делал и по одному, зачем мне циклы, если что то произойдёт я смогу знать на какой строке что то произошло, и клиент не будет ждать когда выполниться запрос. Так что не нужно считать свой ответ панацеей

Comment: Если запрос уязвим к инъекциям, то совершенно неважно, с какой скоростью он выполняется. Очень жаль, что современные веб-разработчики не понимают таких базовых вещей.

Comment: Мда уж ребятки у каждого свое. Я бы не делал на очередях а сразу фильтровал внешние данные ну если ты конечно работаешь над банковским приложением то безусловно там нужен жесткий контроль и транзакции и проверки на успех и т д а малому бизнесу нужно как говорится хуяк хуяк и в продакшн. Разработчики веб студий меня поймут

Comment: Студии разные бывают, немного работал с рубедитом там вас бы даже держать не стали, всё зависит от того как вы делает продукт и как себя продаёте... Если вы себя продаёте как качественный разработчик то вы и делаете качественно и явно без видимых с небольшого взгляда дыр(иньекция это прям та ещё дыра), и приложение ваше будет работать быстро а не херак херак и в продакшн... Так вообще делать не есть хорошо, как минимум вначале на дев или тест сервер

Comment: Возможно в каких-то вебстудиях такой подход и приемлем, но на stack overflow - нет. И, кстати, здесь не приветствуется люмпен-лексикон. Лучше удалить эти словечки.

Comment: Да веб студии бывают разные, тут вопрос не столько в веб студии а в вознограждении. Соответсвенно чем больше бюджет тем качественее продукт, тем глубже понимание технологий. А в рядовых веб студиях я вас уверяю как раз таки не качество а время играет роль, проработал во множество вебстудиях Москвы

Comment: Если так оценивать то я бы за такой код и 500 рублей не заплатил бы... Наверное пора прекращать дискуссию не в тему вопроса

Comment: Так это мой первый пост тут я незнаю зачем вы тратите на меня свое время)